# Convert NSString to Int

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I try to convert `NSString` to `int`,Result dpPoint:0, I want  dpPoint:2

```
dpPointStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[verifyRow valueForKey:@"default_point"]];
NSLog(@"dpPointStr:%@",dpPointStr); //Result dpPointStr:2

int dpPoint = [dpPointStr intValue];
NSLog(@"dpPoint:%i",dpPoint); //Result dpPoint:0
```

Comment: I think your code should work.  Is that the actual code?  According to the reference `intValue` only returns 0 if: " the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid decimal text representation of a number".

Comment: I would say not you use int, go for NSInteger. You should always use a wrapper class.

Comment: It's really code![to trojanfoe]
if i write it below,
NSString *str1 = @"2";
int dpPoint = [dpPointStr intValue];
NSLog(@"dpPoint:%i",dpPoint); //Result will be dpPoint:2

Comment: [To Anoop Vaidya]
NSInteger dpPoint = [dpPointStr integerValue];
NSLog(@"dpPoint:%i",dpPoint); //Result will be dpPoint:0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, if value is in the beginning/end of the string you can try this:

```
int val = [[dpPointStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] intValue];
```

Comment: Thanks a lots..I was trying to figure out this problem for several hours and +1!

Comment: It's really sad that one has to go to this tremendous extreme just to get the numerical value out of an NSString.

Answer (score 0):

```
int str_len = [yourStr length]; char tmp[str_len];

[NSString getCString:tmp maxLength:str_len encoding:UTF8Encoding];

int dpPoint = atoi(tmp);
```

Don't forget to include this: #include

I think this should work just fine.

Also, I think you can fix this by taking the intValue from the:

```
[verifyRow valueForKey:@"default_point"];
```

To be consistent with Apple use NSInteger instead, or even better NSNumber for the valueForKey statement and then NSInteger.

Answer (score -1):

Convert NSString to integer

```
NSString *sampleText = @"5";

int numValue = [sampleText intValue];

NSLog(@"Integer Value: %d", numValue);
```